# Visual Composer Data Source?

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy, visual-editor

So, all im trying to accomplish is getting my product categories from WooCommerce to post on a page in the Visual Composer Masonry format. But (as you can see in the pic) the Product Categories is blacked out in the data source option. And nothing displays when I enter it in.

screenshot: [image: screenshot]

I basically just want a masonry grid with post category featured images that link to the categories page.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the raw category template in the woocommerce files.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product category thumbnails within loops
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product_cat.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.6.1
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
?>
<li <?php wc_product_cat_class( '', $category ); ?>>
    <?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_subcategory hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_category_link_open - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory', $category );

    /**
     * woocommerce_before_subcategory_title hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', $category );

    /**
     * woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_category_title - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', $category );

    /**
     * woocommerce_after_subcategory_title hook.
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', $category );

    /**
     * woocommerce_after_subcategory hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_category_link_close - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory', $category ); ?>
</li>
```